# Create a two parallel planes given three points (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, raycasting

I'm trying to create an advanced raycaster. How would I write a function that would create two [grids (image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUiiT.png) based on 3 points? I want the output to be two arrays filled with {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0} objects for each intersection shown in the image. Hopefully this isn't too difficult to understand. The reason I want this is so that I can have a ray cast from each pixel on the screen.

Comment: dotproduct and crossproduct are your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's vector c=CB, vector a=AB. You can get the second base vector for planes as

```
d = c X a  (cross product)
```

get unit base vectors

```
ua = Normalized(a) = a / Length(a)
ud = Normalized(d)
```

and build grid (cell size is ASize x DSize) points as

```
P[i,j] = B + ua * i * ASize + ud * j * DSize
   for the first plane

Q[i,j] = C + ua * i * ASize + ud * j * DSize
   for the second plane
```

Comment: Can you explain more in depth the last block of code? In JavaScript is P(i,j) two loops inside of each other?

Comment: Yes, 2d array with grid vertices might be filled in two loops (`for i... for j.... P[i,j]=...`)

Comment: If I wanted the output to be an array of {x: 0, y: 0, z:0}, what would I put instead of  'B + ua * i * ASize + ud * j * DSize'

Comment: component-wise expressions like `x = B.X + ua.X * i * ASize + ud.X * j * DSize`

Comment: In what order would the grid be made? I looped through grid 1, and depending on if there was an intersection between (sphere.pos, sphere.radius, this.raycastGrids.grid1[i], this.raycastGrids.grid2[i], intersection), I drew a black circle at var xDraw = i % this.width;
        var yDraw = Math.floor(i/this.width);. It didn't seem to work though, it only drew a lot of lines at different lengths.

Comment: To draw grid, you may draw lines between P[i,j] and P[i,j+1] (in 2d - to the right point), and between P[i,j] and P[i+1,j] (in 2d - to the bottom point)

Comment: Wait so is the output in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] form relative to the grid?

Comment: I don't understand... 2D example: formula generates points (0,0), (0,1),(0,2)..(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)... Grid lines (0,0)-(0,1) and (0,0)-(1,0) and so on

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying. What exactly do you mean by 2D example? This is a 3d game. My output for this function is two arrays like [tuple1a, tuple2a, tuple3a, tuple4a] and [tuple1b, tuple2b, tuple3b, tuple4b]. I cast vectors starting from tuple1a that intersect tuple1b. If it intersects, I draw a black square on the canvas. Is this the correct usage of your formula?

Comment: Because example for 2D is simple.

Comment: 2D is simple to demonstrate, but technique is the same  - for 3D we just add 3rd coordinate. It is not clear for me - what are the tuples intended for? Do they contain coordinates? Coordinates of what objects?